# arrow keys are not working with terminal server telnet (termnetd) session

Tags: bash, terminal, readline

I am using terminal server package `termnetd 3.2`, which reads serial port and gives output on telnet port. I logged into terminal server port, every thing works fine except the arrow keys, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys.

I updated bash to `bash 4.2`, with latest `readline` package. Still the issue remains same. Is handling arrow keys related to readline library or termios' settings ??

Comment: According to bash man page it says handling of special keys done by readline,when i pressed up arrow key it shows ^[[A ,but it executes previous command which was typed.

Comment: Doesn't the result of pressing up arrow depend on what the serial port is connect to ? What are the serial ports connect to?

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason for bash disagreeing with cursor- and editing-keypad keys is that many terminal descriptions (such as vt100 and xterm) switch the terminal into *application mode* when initialized (using the `smkx` terminfo / `ks` termcap escape sequence).  bash doesn't do that (nor does the `linux` terminal description, not coincidentally), and unless your `.inputrc` is sprinkled with extra bindings to account for the unexpected key sequences sent in application mode, you'll have problems with bash.

The readline **library** as such doesn't know the difference between normal/application mode.  Likewise, termios is unrelated to the problem.

It's an FAQ of course:

- [My cursor keys do not work](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode) (ncurses FAQ)
- [Why can't I use the cursor keys in (whatever) shell?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows) (xterm FAQ)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)+<kbd>End</kbd> and (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)+<kbd>Home</kbd>